# How can you set the command prompt to use the downloaded Python as an interpreter?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, command-prompt

When I want to execute Python in my command prompt, Windows always redirects me to the windows store to download Python. But I've already installed Python (python.org). So how can I adjust, that the command prompt uses the downloaded Python?

Comment: Sorry for my English... I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: What are you typing in the cmd?

Comment: just python or I also tried python3

Comment: try typing just py

Comment: Glad I helped!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `py` instead of `python` or `python3`